# How to get random number or string in transact email?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to generate random number or string in forgot password template?
I used directly "getRandomString(6)" that print same thing?
I did not get how should i change?

Comment: Try this: $customer.generatePassword(6). Not tested

Comment: It does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento Way, You can use Follwoing code for generate random string.

```
$randomString = Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString($length = 6);
```

If you want to put it in Password field in form.use the below

```
<?php $password = Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString($length = 7)?>

<input type="hidden" name="password" id="password" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" value="<?php echo $password?>"  />
```

Comment: I want to generate a verification code as a token in forgot password email...how can i generate that code?

Comment: So you want it in php code,correct?

Answer (score 0):

An other possible script in magento way for a link hash is:

```
$key = Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString($length = 12);;
$uniqid = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
$hash = md5($key . $uniqid);
return $hash;
```